# How many partitions does Kafka broker support

Tags: apache-kafka

What is the limit of Kafka partitions that a Kafka broker can support? and if there is no limit, how many partition per Broker makes my cluster turn well and fast?

Answer (score 2):

As of the recent blogs, [200K+ partitions per cluster](https://blogs.apache.org/kafka/entry/apache-kafka-supports-more-partitions), but that of course heavily depends on the actual hardware you run, and how well you can maintain Kafka up to that point. I doubt a Raspberry Pi will be able to handle that much load, for example.

There isn't exactly a hard limit per broker, but the old rule of thumb was less than 1000 partitions on average per broker will keep the cluster working optimally

That blog says 4000 is now a good number

> As a rule of thumb, we recommend each broker to have up to 4,000 partitions and each cluster to have up to 200,000 partitions

Answer (score 1):

Recording to [apache blog](https://blogs.apache.org/kafka/entry/apache-kafka-supports-more-partitions), the Limit that a Kafka broker can support up to 4,000 partitions and each cluster up to 200,000 partitions.